# issues using react data table with a large set of data

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I have a flask server that I'm using to fetch some large data. I would like to present this data in a react data table. (I'm using redux to save the data in a global state)

```
return (
  <DataTable
    title="Some data"
    columns={columns}
    data={globalState.data}
  />
)
```

My issue is that once i load the data, my app barely moves, and im getting:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at mountFiberRecursively

My data is saved in the redux global state.

Am i doing anything wrong? does it re-renders the entire data all the time and theres a different way i should load the data into that DataTable? and not from the global state?